# Sentry logging using log4j not working

Tags: java, logging, log4j, sentry

I am writing an app that is using log4j as its logging tool. I tried to hook it up to Sentry.io tracking, but I get the following exception each time when I try to log something:

```
2016-09-27 13:38:13 WARN  EventBuilder$HostnameCache:625 - Localhost
hostname lookup failed, keeping the value 'unavailable'
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
at com.getsentry.raven.event.EventBuilder$HostnameCache.updateCache(EventBuilder.java:620)
at com.getsentry.raven.event.EventBuilder$HostnameCache.getHostname(EventBuilder.java:606)
at com.getsentry.raven.event.EventBuilder.autoSetMissingValues(EventBuilder.java:90)
at com.getsentry.raven.event.EventBuilder.build(EventBuilder.java:360)
at com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender.buildEvent(SentryAppender.java:252)
at com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender.append(SentryAppender.java:174)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.fatal(Category.java:382)
at com.pikmy.core.PikmyServer.main(PikmyServer.java:21)
```

I have set up my log4j.xaml file just like it was described in the documentation present here:
https://sentry.io/pikmy-ltd/pikmy-api/settings/install/java-log4j/

What could be the possible problem with sending data to Sentry?

**More information:**

The log4j.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="sentry" class="com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender">
        <param name="dsn" value="SENTRY_URL_HERE"/>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
          <param name="levelMin" value="WARN"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>

<root>
    <priority value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="sentry" />
</root>
```

I tested the logging with a simple exception like this:

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PikmyServer.class.getName());
try {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   log.fatal("Test", ex);
}
```

Log4j.xml is placed in the resources, so the logger gets the configuration by default.

Comment: Could you please show the code where you initialize your logger and where you attempt logging. The error points to a host-name lookup fail - but seeing the code might shed some more light.

Comment: I supplied more information in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this was a problem with the internet configuration being blocked locally. I switched the internet source from an open connection to a private one and everything just magically started working.